# Why concat is also showing in this select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Generate the following two result sets:

1. Query an *alphabetically ordered* list of all names in **OCCUPATIONS**, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: `AnActorName(A)`, `ADoctorName(D)`, `AProfessorName(P)`, and `ASingerName(S)`.
2. Query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in **OCCUPATIONS**. Sort the occurrences in *ascending order*, and output them in the following format:

   ```
   There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.
   ```

   where `[occupation_count]` is the number of occurrences of an occupation in **OCCUPATIONS** and `[occupation]` is the *lowercase* occupation name. If more than one *Occupation* has the same `[occupation_count]`, they should be ordered alphabetically.

My queries:

```
select concat(name, '(', substring(occupation, 1, 1), ')')
from occupations;

select concat('There are a total of', ' ', count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation),'s.')
from occupations
group by occupation
order by COUNT(occupation);
```

in output

| concat(name, '(', substring(occupation, 1, 1), ')') |
| --- |
| Aamina(D) |
| Ashley(P) |
| Belvet(P) |
| Britney(P) |
| Christeen(S) |
| Eve(A) |
| Jane(S) |
| Jennifer(A) |
| Jenny(S) |
| Julia(D) |
| Ketty(A) |
| Kristeen(S) |
| Maria(P) |
| Meera(P) |
| Naomi(P) |
| Priya(D) |
| Priyanka(P) |
| Samantha(A) |

and

| concat('There are a total of', ' ', count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation),'s.') |
| --- |
| There are a total of 3 doctors. |
| There are a total of 4 actors. |
| There are a total of 4 singers. |
| There are a total of 7 professors. |

Comment: What is this supposed to be? Why is there a random list of names? Please ask a proper question -- and since this is clearly your homework, look also in the help section for questions about homeworks.

Comment: This is a very popular question lately perhaps from many people in the same class...any way .when you don't provide a column name or an ALIAS mysql will provide a column name based on what it knows..btw that isn't A query it's 2 queries.

Comment: I have used alias after that and the column name is also coming in output but in the expected output the column name is not there so its showing wrong is there any way to not show column name @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **as** after the **concate** function and add a column name. Here is an example:

```
select concat(name, '(', substring(occupation, 1, 1), ')') as `Custom Column Name`
from occupations;
```

This will rewrite the column name to `Custom Column Name`. Replace the "Custom Column Name" value with desired one.

Similarly you can change the column name of your second query like this:

select concat(name, '(', substring(occupation, 1, 1), ')')
from occupations;

```
select concat('There are a total of', ' ', count(occupation), ' ', lower(occupation),'s.') as `Custom Column Name` from occupations group by occupation order by COUNT(occupation);
```

This will change your output like this

| Custom Column Name |
| --- |
| Aamina(D) |
| Ashley(P) |